# Dope Sheet: Select all keyframes before or after a certain point

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

I'm attempting to create a smooth motion with a camera object in an animation as it changes location between several keyframes. My goal is to select the relevant keyframes at the specific point in time and move them forward or backward on the dope sheet timeline.

This of course only moves the selected keyframes at that specific moment, without altering any other keyframes elsewhere on the timeline, which means I would need to manually offset every other keyframe located after the one changed.

While the B and C hotkeys can help achieve this goal to either select everything ahead of the keyframes being adjusted, this may become more time consuming for any future projects that might be more complicated. Is there a function or hotkey I am unaware of which would allow me to include every keyframe ahead of the selected one? And if such a function exists, does the opposite exist as well (include all keyframes before selected one)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Left square bracket (<kbd>[</kbd>) and right square bracket (<kbd>]</kbd>) will select all keyframes on all channels before or after the current frame respectively, *including* the current frame.

If you don't want the current frame included you will have to change the current frame by 1, left or right, depending on the selection direction.

Comment: Also Ctrl right click, will do the job (on the left or right of the current frame)

Comment: You guys are awesome. Both will definitely come in handy.

Comment: seems not to work as of blender 3.1
or is it my QWERTZ layout?

Comment: @Georodin Works for me in 3.2.

Comment: lol I just noticed that I bought yesterday your render border addon
small world

Comment: it is indeed my QWERTZ layout
because I can only access the brackets over ALT GR + 8 or 9
checked it in the keymappings

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to create 2 [markers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/markers.html) and select all the keyframes between them.

Move the current frame to desired position and [create a marker](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/markers.html#add-marker) with <kbd>M</kbd> or from *Marker* > *Add Marker* in the Dope Sheet header. Then do the same for the other one.
Then select these markers by clicking <kbd>RMB</kbd> and holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select multiple.
Once they are ready and selected in the Select menu find *Between Selected Markers* function.

[image: screenshot-1]