# How to select multiple keyframes in the dopesheet

Tags: animation, keyframes

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how do i select multiple keyframes at once, i need to delete half of my keyframes in my animation, but do i need to select each one individually?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: That should be the same as multiple selection in any other editor - Shift+Right click, Shift + Box Selext, Shift+Circle Select etc. etc. Maybe it can be faster to select keyframes past certain point, then related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79681/dope-sheet-select-all-keyframes-before-or-after-a-certain-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go to your Dope Sheet, Press <kbd>B</kbd> for "box Select" and **drag the left click button to select the keyframes** and perform the operation you want.

Comment: Only the 3D view has the right click to select thing. Plus the box select tool even in the 3D view used the left mouse button for selection, right cancels the modal.